# Is there a way to get this/context out from method?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I have done this function in JavaScript:

```
var syncCall = function( cb, obj, fn ) {
   var params = [];
   for( var i=3; i< arguments.length; i++ ) {
      params.push( arguments[i] );
   }
   fn.apply( obj, params )
      .onReject( function( result ){
         console.error( result );
       } )
       .onFulfill( function( result ){
          if( cb != undefined && cb != null ) {
             cb( result );
          }
       });
};
```

The problem is, that I have to passs `obj` param into `syncCall function, to set proper context of`this`inside`fn` when it is called.

In my case, `fn` is always a method/function, that is stored in one of `obj` properties. So normally when executing for example `obj.myFunctionname()`, the `this` operator inside `myFunctionname` refers to `obj`. I am wondering, if I can take an adventage of that fact. Meaning, when having `fn` as a parameter to `syncCall`, take somehow the context ( which is `obj` ) and pass it properly to `apply()` function as first parameter (thus, resign from having obj as second input parameter in `syncCall()` )

Comment: *this* isn't "context", it's just a parameter that is set in the call or using *bind*. If you want to call *syncCall* as `obj.syncCall` so that *this* within the function is *obj*, then add it to *Object.prototype* so you'd do `obj.syncCall(cb, fn)` and `...fn.apply(this,param)...`. Be aware that doing that is disliked because it can break poorly written for..in loops. So you could have an *Obj* constructor and have `Obj.prototype.syncCall`.

Comment: @RobG I've tried this an You where totally right. The objects I have tried to extend by prototyping had some for..in construction, and started to behave unexpected while having new property/function asyncCall. Thus I have chosen solution proposed by 'thesebas' below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of obj param fn should be context (this) agnostic because you should be able pass as `fn` any callable (eg. anonymous function that do not use this) so 1) pass function bound to obj or 2) leave context as is and call .apply w/o context param `fn.apply(null, params)`:

1) if called anywhere bound fn to obj:

```
syncCall(cb, fn.bind(obj))
```

or

2) if called inside obj context leave fn as is

```
obj = {

 fn: function(){
  // some logic to be done in syncCall
 },

 someObjMethod: function(){
   syncCall(cb, this.fn); //here this == obj and will be inside syncCall
 }
}
```

Comment: p.s.: By convention cb is last param so swap it in `syncCall` signature to have `syncCall(fn, cb)` :)